# Playing local + online coop with one headphone set

Tags: xbox-360, audio-hardware

I wish to play from my XBox with a friend of mine on some game that allow local (split-screen) + online co-op. I only have one headphone set, though.

Is it possibile to have the audio incoming from online partners routed to the TV set while still having a headphone attached to the controller so that we can speak?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. In the settings (I can't recall where atm, unfortunately), there is an option to have voice chat go to your headset, to your TV along with game audio, or both. If you set it to go to your TV both players should be able to hear voice chat.